# Where is the kernel documentation?

Tags: kernel, documentation

In CentOS I can do `yum install kernel-doc` and then read `/usr/share/doc/kernel-doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt`.

How would I do the equivalent in Ubuntu?  Professor Google told me it was in the source code so I did `apt install linux-source` but I can't find `proc.txt` anywhere.

I'm guessing there's a different way of doing it in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The package name is linux-doc, after you `apt install linux-doc` look in `/usr/share/doc/linux-doc`.

In general anything that would be called "kernel" in RH/CentOS land will be called "linux" in Ubuntu since Ubuntu is based on Debian which has versions with other kernels like GNU Hurd and BSD.

Comment: Calling your kernel packages `kernel` makes about as much sense as calling your Firefox packages `web-browser`...

Comment: Note that many of the files are left compressed, so `proc.txt` is `/usr/share/doc/linux-doc/filesystems/proc.txt.gz`. Less will decompress it on the fly.